# Cannot save site as template due to workflow history list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I get this error when saving site as a template and including the content...

> Error exporting the list named "Workflow history" at the URL:
>   Lists/Workflow History.

Using SP2010

Comment: I believe it may have something to do with the workflow history list containing 6000+ items. Is there a safe way to delete them without breaking the WF's in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the items from workflow history list, it is same like any other list.

> A workflow is made up of a sequence of events such as workflow
>   initiation, task creation, and task completion. When you add a
>   workflow, you specify a task list and a history list that workflow
>   instances of that workflow association will use to track the events
>   for the workflow. The task list contains items that users interact
>   with and enter data into while interacting with a workflow. The
>   workflow history contains key information about each event including
>   date, status, participant, and description.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also Make sure the Workflow Auto Cleanup timer job is configured to run daily. if you want to delete them programatically please check these.

http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=111

http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/09/archiving-your-sharepoint-workflow-history-lists/

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/Cleanup-Workflow-History-cee6e75e

Comment: Thanks. I have set a retention policy but did not know about the 'Workflow auto clean-up timer job' so will check this out.